# Read Messages from IBM MQ and send to Azure Eventhub

Tags: apache-camel, spring-kafka

I am reading messages from IBM MQ using camel and doing some kind of enhancement and after that using spring Kafka template to send messages to azure eventhub. As KafkaTemplate.send is async process, camel acknowledging to IBM MQ before the actually message send to Eventhub. Is there a way we can acknowledge to IBM MQ only after message published to EventHub??

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the `Future<?>` returned by `KafkaTemplate.send()` to complete (with a timeout).

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell. Is there any performance hit because of this if messages volume is high ?

Comment: Yes, of course; it will hold up the message listener until the record is secured in Kafka.

Comment: with synchronous process we see perf impact is high. Is there a way to make sure messages not to lost in Async process in case  of forceful shutdown or some unexpected VM issues ?